# Check if Wi-Fi is downloading

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to check if the Wi-Fi is currently active in the sense that it is downloading in the background?

From what I see in the documentation (and other research) it seems that it is only possible to check and see if Wi-Fi is connected to a network. However, it is not possible to check whether there is any data transfer activity going on for that particular network.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003350/android-check-if-downloads-are-active

It might help you

Comment: Here's an [open source app](http://code.google.com/p/iptableslog/) that does what you want and much more, though it requires root privileges.

Comment: @user3249477 any code i can see of urs so that i can get idea of what u r extactly trying?

Comment: I'm only trying to provide you with a helpful link :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html).

You can get total download by `TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();` and total upload by `TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();`.

You can store initial values of them in a variable and occasionally check if there is a difference between initial value and current value. You can use a timer for this.

This article about [Create a network monitor using Android's TrafficStats class](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()` will return the total bytes on all interfaces since boot. Subtract `TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()` from it to get closer to Wifi bytes used, do the same for '...RxBytes'. Maintain some sort of persistence for this result, poll periodically and look at the delta.